# How to filter and get each object key's value using startsWith?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to filter an object by getting each key starting with `checkpoint` and outputting its value. At the moment, I am only able to output the key rather than the value. Below, I have a simple object. I am using the filter and startsWith. How can I get the values instead?

```js
var data = {
  practicals: '0',
  checkpoint01: '0',
  checkpoint02: '0',
  checkpoint03: '0',
  checkpoint04: '0',
  checkpoint05: '0',
  checkpoint06: '0',
  checkpoint07: '0',
  checkpoint08: '0',
  checkpoint09: '0',
  checkpoint10: '0',
  total: '0'
}

var res = Object.keys(data).filter(v => v.startsWith('checkpoint'))

console.log(res)

// This is the current output: ["checkpoint01", "checkpoint02", "checkpoint03", "checkpoint04", "checkpoint05", "checkpoint06", "checkpoint07", "checkpoint08", "checkpoint09", "checkpoint10"]

// This is the expected output I want: [ '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0' ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One more alternative is to use test, and `i` flag if you need case insensitivity

```
/^checkpoint/i
```

- `^` - Start of string
- `checkpoint` - match word checkpoint

---

```js
var data = {practicals: '0',checkpoint01: '0',checkpoint02: '0',checkpoint03: '0',checkpoint04: '0',checkpoint05: '0',checkpoint06: '0',checkpoint07: '0',checkpoint08: '0',checkpoint09: '0',checkpoint10: '0',total: '0'}

var final = Object.keys(data)
            .filter(value => /^checkpoint/i.test(value))
            .map(e => data[e])

console.log(final)
```

If you need to match a range of number after word checkpoint, you can extend the pattern

```
 `/^checkpoint[0-6]?/`
```

- `[0-6]?` - This will allow any number between 0 to 6, ( optional )

Comment: The range is not working when I put this in @codemaniac

```var final = Object.keys(data)
            .filter(value => /^checkpoint[0-6]?/i.test(value))
            .map(e => data[e])```

Comment: @User123 `[0-6]? will match either one time or not`, you need quantifiers if you need to includes more number, `you can use \d* which means match any digit between 0 to 9, zero or more time`

Comment: Could you please explain in code? Not the best at regex and working with them @codemaniac

Comment: @User123 you can watch  out this [`number range regex generator`](http://gamon.webfactional.com/regexnumericrangegenerator/), if you still find any difficulty let me know

Answer (score 8):

Use `Array.prototype.map` with `data` variable.

```js
var data = {
  practicals: '0',
  checkpoint01: '0',
  checkpoint02: '0',
  checkpoint03: '0',
  checkpoint04: '0',
  checkpoint05: '0',
  checkpoint06: '0',
  checkpoint07: '0',
  checkpoint08: '0',
  checkpoint09: '0',
  checkpoint10: '0',
  total: '0'
}

var res = Object.keys(data).filter(v => v.startsWith('checkpoint')).map(e => data[e])

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 3):

One way you could do this is to use `Object.entries()` instead of `Object.keys()` to get an array of key-value pairs. Then use `.filter()` to keep all entries which have a key that start with `"checkpoint"` and `.map()` to map your inner arrays to their value:

```js
const data = { practicals: '0', checkpoint01: '0', checkpoint02: '0', checkpoint03: '0', checkpoint04: '0', checkpoint05: '0', checkpoint06: '0', checkpoint07: '0', checkpoint08: '0', checkpoint09: '0', checkpoint10: '0', total: '0' };

const res = Object.entries(data)
              .filter(([k]) => k.startsWith('checkpoint'))
              .map(([,v]) => v);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: One more question how could I get the range say, for instance, I want to get checkpoint1 to checkpoint6

Comment: @User123 easiest way would probably be to use regular expressions then, see [Code Maniac's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58007798/5648954) for that approach.

Answer (score 1):

```
let result = [];
let keysArr = Object.keys(data);
keysArr.forEach((eachKey,index)=>{
    if(eachKey.startsWith('checkpoint')){
        result.push(data[eachKey]);
    }
})
```

Please try the above code

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it without using one liner tidy-ups (awesome though) like `.map` `.keys` or `.entries`. With a single `for-in` loop on keys of the `object`.

```js
const data = {
  practicals: "0",
  checkpoint01: "0",
  checkpoint02: "0",
  checkpoint03: "0",
  checkpoint04: "0",
  checkpoint05: "0",
  checkpoint06: "0",
  checkpoint07: "0",
  checkpoint08: "0",
  checkpoint09: "0",
  checkpoint10: "0",
  total: "0"
};

let result = [];
for (const key in data) {
  //regex test could be used instead for case-insensitivity
  if (key.startsWith("checkpoint")) {
    result.push(data[key]);
  }
}
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = {
    practicals: '0',
    checkpoint01: '0',
    checkpoint02: '0',
    checkpoint03: '0',
    checkpoint04: '0',
    checkpoint05: '0',
    checkpoint06: '0',
    checkpoint07: '0',
    checkpoint08: '0',
    checkpoint09: '0',
    checkpoint10: '0',
    total: '0'
};

let res = [];
Object.keys(data).map((key) => {
    console.log(key)
    if(key.startsWith('checkpoint'))
        res.push(data[key])
})
console.log(res)
```